# How to limit my kids to playing on my own server or each-other's worlds?

Tags: android, xbox-network, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My kids like playing Minecraft on their Android tablets or the oldest's PC, and I would like them to be able to play in each-other's worlds, as well as my own Bedrock server.

However, in enabling them to play with each other and on my own server, I have also allowed them to access public servers.

Is there some way that I can deny them access to the public servers, or in fact any server other than my own or their own LAN games - without having to firewall my network?  I already have the kids' tablets and PC locked down so they cannot access anything my wife or I deem unsuitable... except these advertised Minecraft servers.

The kids all have kids XBox-live accounts connected to my own as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft doesn't provide in-game options for that. Why can't you firewall the router?

TBH minecraft servers don't really have nsfw content. The worst you can find is at most some mild or obscure swears, as Microsoft did implement a swear filter. Most illegal acts, e.g. pedos finding children, scamming etc are quickly reported as long as they are going on the advertised servers or some other big ones. They have to face these things anyways when they are older, why not educate them about scams earlier?

Comment: Do *you* know the public server IP addresses?